how do i limit the scene to 360 degrees flutter
When doing a 360 degree turn in my Flutter application, the dot disappears instead of appearing. I have a scene with placed dots, and I use a gyroscope to update the position of the dots. However, when I rotate the device 360 degrees, the dot disappears instead of remaining visible. How can I fix this problem?
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:sensors/sensors.dart';
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:math';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: '360',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: AnchorInSpace(),
    );
  }
}

class AnchorInSpace extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _AnchorInSpaceState createState() => _AnchorInSpaceState();
}

class _AnchorInSpaceState extends State<AnchorInSpace> {
  double _x = 0.0, _y = 0.0;
  bool _isInside = false;
  Timer? _timer;
  int? _scannedPoint;

  Map<int, List<int>> pointsMap = {
    1: [14, 2, 32, 13],
    // Other points mappings...
    50: [48, 51],
    51: [50, 49],
  };

  Map<int, Offset> pointsPositions = {
    // Positions of points...
  };

  Set<int> activePoints = {1}; // Starting point
  Set<int> replacedPoints = {};

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    gyroscopeEvents.listen((GyroscopeEvent event) {
      setState(() {
        _x += event.y * 5;
        _y += event.x * 5;
        _checkIfInsideCircle();
      });
    });
  }

  void _checkIfInsideCircle() {
    final double redCircleRadius = 30;
    final double whiteCircleRadius = 35;

    final double whiteCircleCenterX = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 2;
    final double whiteCircleCenterY = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 2;

    _scannedPoint = null;

    for (var point in activePoints) {
      final double redCircleCenterX =
          whiteCircleCenterX + pointsPositions[point]!.dx + _x;
      final double redCircleCenterY =
          whiteCircleCenterY + pointsPositions[point]!.dy + _y;

      final double distance = sqrt((redCircleCenterX - whiteCircleCenterX) *
          (redCircleCenterX - whiteCircleCenterX) +
          (redCircleCenterY - whiteCircleCenterY) *
              (redCircleCenterY - whiteCircleCenterY));

      if (distance <= (whiteCircleRadius - redCircleRadius)) {
        _scannedPoint = point;
        if (!_isInside) {
          _isInside = true;
          _startCountdown();
        }
        return;
      }
    }

    _isInside = false;
    _timer?.cancel();
  }

  void _startCountdown() {
    _timer?.cancel();
    _timer = Timer(Duration(seconds: 1), () {
      if (_scannedPoint != null) {
        setState(() {
          replacedPoints.add(_scannedPoint!);
          _activateNeighbors(_scannedPoint!);
        });
      }
    });
  }

  void _activateNeighbors(int point) {
    if (pointsMap.containsKey(point)) {
      pointsMap[point]?.forEach((neighbor) {
        if (!replacedPoints.contains(neighbor) &&
            !activePoints.contains(neighbor)) {
          activePoints.add(neighbor);
        }
      });
    }
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _timer?.cancel();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
        elevation: 0,
        title: Text('360'),
        foregroundColor: Colors.deepPurple,
        centerTitle: true,
        leading: IconButton(
          icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_back, color: Colors.deepPurple),
          onPressed: () {},
        ),
        actions: [
          IconButton(
            icon: Icon(Icons.help_outline, color: Colors.deepPurple),
            onPressed: () {},
          ),
        ],
      ),
      body: LayoutBuilder(
        builder: (context, constraints) {
          return Stack(
            children: [
              Container(color: Colors.black),
              // Points rendering...
              // Progress indicator...
            ],
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}


I tried limiting the scene to 360 degrees, however my points did not behave correctly
